# VBProject Tools-->VBA Project Propeties password protected

Tags: excel, vba

Is there any way i can change the project property? When i go to VB screen in an excel sheet , i see that the Tools-->VBA Project Properties is password protected.

Answer (score 0):

I've had some success with this method in the past, i.e. I have managed to unlock some VBA projects with it, but with other files it has failed for some unknown reason.

- Close the workbook and open the workbook file in a hex editor.
- Find the string "DPB" and change it to "DPx". Save the file.
- Open the workbook and click OK until the workbook is open (one or more dialogs are displayed describing various problems with the VBA project).
- Press ALT+F11, choose the menu command `Tools->VBAProject Properties`, navigate to the Protection tab, and change the password but do not remove it (note the new password).
- Save, close, and re-open the workbook.
- Press ALT+F11 and enter the new password.
- Choose `Tools->VBAProject Properties`, navigate to the Protection tab, and remove the password.
- Save the workbook.

As ever, make a backup before you attempt to change anything as you may be left with a corrupt file if this fails.

Comment: Yes, it only seems to work with certain files, but I've no idea what would constitute a suitable candidate for it working.